# Exception in destructor while using = overload function

Tags: c++, exception, destructor

I have a class for polynomials. Function of + overloading works but I couldn’t use = overloading function because of exception! 
I debugged the program and saw exception is in destructor, I don’t know how to fix it!

```
polynomial::~polynomial()
{
    delete[] coeff;
}

const polynomial& polynomial::operator=(const polynomial& p)
{

    if(this == &p)
        return *this;

    polynomial tmp(p);

    std::swap(maxPoly, tmp.maxPoly);
    std::swap(coeff, tmp.coeff);
    return *this;
}

void polynomial::add(const polynomial& aPoly)
{
    if(aPoly.maxPoly > maxPoly)
        grow(aPoly.maxPoly);

    for(int i = 0; i < (int) maxPoly; i++)
        coeff[i] += aPoly.coeff[i];
}
polynomial::polynomial()
{
    coeff = new int[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        coeff[i] = 0;
    }
    maxPoly = 10;
}
polynomial::polynomial(int size){
    coeff = new int[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        coeff[i] = 0;
    }
    maxPoly = size;
}
        polynomial::polynomial(const polynomial& aPoly)
    {
        coeff = new int[aPoly.maxPoly];
        for (int i = 0; i < aPoly.maxPoly; i++)
        {
            coeff[i] = aPoly.coeff[i];
        }
        maxPoly = aPoly.maxPoly;
    }
```

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: I think that you most probably `delete` the same memory twice. So the problem actually is not in the destructor but in your copy constructor.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/vcd3c1g3uaaqdlk/exception.png?dl=0

Comment: @Anton: I add constructor and copy constructor. what's the problem?

Comment: Do we have to guess what the exception is?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: you can see exception in this picture: https://www.dropbox.com/s/vcd3c1g3uaaqdlk/exception.png?dl=0

Comment: You haven't shown us the copy constructor. And why are you juggling pointers when `std::vector` already does this correctly?

Comment: @MikeSeymour: I added copy constructor and I don't use std::vector.

Comment: @NASRIN: I don't see a copy constructor; just a default constructor, a constructor taking `size_t`, and a copy-assignment operator. And you should use `std::vector`, that would make this much simpler and less error-prone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this code:
**polynomial tmp(p);**.
When tmp goes out of scope it's being deleted and the destructor is called for it. So **delete[]coeff;** is being called, deleting your coeff, allocated on heap. What you should do in your assignment operator is to:

1. delete[] coeff
2. assign p.maxPoly to maxPoly
3. allocate memory for new coeff. coeff = new double[maxPoly]
4. copy all coefficients to your new array. Like that

   for( int i = 0; i < maxPoly; ++i )coeff[i] = p.coeff[i];

That should be fine.

It seems that in your implementation you have troubles with copy constructor. Have you defined it? If not, you should do this, because memory allocated on heap isn't copied automatically in standard copy constructor.

Comment: I do step 2 and 4 , in assignment operator function:
std::swap(maxPoly, tmp.maxPoly);
 std::swap(coeff, tmp.coeff);
and allocate memory does in copy constructor. is it wrong?

Comment: Please, provide the code of your copy constructor

Comment: I edited the question and added code of my copy constructor.

Comment: What he should do is not any of that but simply use `std::vector`.

Comment: @Puppy: I don't use stdd::vector

Comment: There is still no copy constructor in your post. The copy constructor looks like `polynomial::polynomial(const polynomial& from){...}`

Comment: @AlexandrLapenkov: You're right! I forgot copy constructor while I added that , the problem works correctly.

Comment: @NASRIN: Then any bugs that you get as a result of that are your own silly fault.

Comment: @Puppy :maybe these bugs is necessary for learning details of a language

Comment: @NASRIN: If you want to learn how to manage memory, it's better to write a memory management class (e.g. a clone of `std::vector`) than to try to bodge memory management into a class whose purpose is to do something else. That will only teach you why it's a bad idea to bodge multiple responsibilities into inappropriate places rather than structuring your code sensibly.